# Is chocolate haram since the average bar apparently has 8 insect parts?

Tags: halal-haram, food

The FDA allows up to 60 insect parts per 100 grams of chocolate. Since all insects (except locusts) are considered haram would consuming these chocolates be haram too. Since it is hard for the companies to completely get rid of the insects since it is expensive and they would have to use more pesticides which would harm us. The FDA allows limited contamination in a lot of foods like frozen vegetables and it is said that insects are in most of our foods and to avoid them you will probably have to stop eating.

Comment: Can you also share your source of reference (link to study/report/paper) for the above statements (chocolates have insect parts in them)? Regards.

Comment: Who said that all insects except locusts are haram?

Comment: @Medi1Saif  Sahih Al-Bukhari Hadith 7.403 Narrated by Ibn Abi Aufa

We participated with the Prophet (saws) in six or seven Ghazawat (Battles), and we used to eat locusts with him

Comment: @Ana that is no prohibition for eating other insects.

Comment: @Ahmed http://www.nbcnews.com/id/46907784/ns/technology_and_science-science/t/chocolate-allergies-linked-cockroach-parts/#.W3hybuhKjIU

Comment: @Medi1Saif There is a difference in opinion between scholars regarding the definition of "filth" when God says in the Quran, “and unlawful all that is filthy” (7:157)  I would rather err on the side of caution